# How do I ensure PHP crypt() works the same way from 5.3.6 to 5.3.7

Tags: php, encryption, hash, crypt

I've just update PHP from 5.3.6 to 5.3.7 and noticed that crypt() isn't giving me the same results.

I've rolled back to the previous version as this is preventing a log-n system from working.

I'd like to know if there's anything I can do to ensure that the same encryption system is used from version to version.

I'm just using it simply, straight out of the manual like this:

```
// make the password    
$newPassword = crypt($_POST['password']);    

// check the password (separate script, using the $newPassword just generated)    
if (crypt($_POST['password'], $newPassword) == $newPassword) {

}
```

Comment: The crypt fn is a front-end to multiple algorithms - which are you using? Did you look at the bug database - .e.g https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55439

Comment: I hadn't checked the bug database, thanks for the link.

Comment: This turns out to be a serious bug; PHP developers are advising not to use 5.3.7 (http://www.php.net/archive/2011.php#id2011-08-22-1).

Answer (score 0):

A suitable test is to write out and use crypt on an arbitary string, then write out the cryptographic data as a string from each version, then compare.

Doubt there will be a much easier way to test it, maybe check version updates on the website as a first resort to save time.

Comment: More formally, you can unit test these things so they are quick and easy to test in a new environment.

Comment: I know that it's not working - I don't need an additional test to tell that. I'm more interested in finding out how to ensure it works correctly in future.

Comment: There's no way for you to ensure it works other than testing it to see if it works. People at PHP are now aware they've [broken something](https://twitter.com/#!/PierreJoye/status/104893151931674625).